# convert duration to ISO 8601 format

Tags: r

Is there a function to convert time durations (outputs from lubridate::duration) to ISO8601 duration format? E.g.

```
lubridate::duration("PT1H3M")
# "3780s (~1.05 hours)"
```

but how would I get the reverse? E.g. the input is

```
"3780s (~1.05 hours)"
```

to get:

```
"PT1H3M"
```

Reference: ISO8601 durations:

https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`format_ISO8601()` from the `lubridate` package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/format_ISO8601.html) works for dates and durations:

```
my_duration <- lubridate::duration("PT1H3M")

my_duration

# [1] "3780s (~1.05 hours)"


lubridate::format_ISO8601(my_duration)

# [1] "PT3780S"
```

but note that the underlying format is not a character string (as your question might suggest):

```
str(my_duration)

# Formal class 'Duration' [package "lubridate"] with 1 slot
#   ..@ .Data: num 3780

lubridate::format_ISO8601("3780s (~1.05 hours)")

# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  # unable to find an inherited method for function ‘format_ISO8601’ for signature ‘"character"’
```